# docker basics: what is the difference between using a Dockerfile and commit?

Tags: docker

If i'm not wrong, a `Dockerfile` allows you to run a series of commands to setup a container.

What is the difference between create a `Dockerfile` and launch a generic image, setup everything on that container using bash and then do a `docker commit` to generate a new image. Is it the same?

Comment: Using a Dockerfile, allows you to employ the [PhoenixServer](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PhoenixServer.html) concept and treat it as code (source-controlled etc.).
Using a docker commit will create an image you won't be able to repeat in creating - you'll have to manually do the same if you wish to fix anything in an underlying layer.

Comment: Why does this have so many downvotes? Can people who downvoted explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way, you're creating an image. The difference is with a Dockerfile, you're making something documented and quickly reproducible. It's like asking "Why use Ansible/Puppet/Chef, when I can just ssh into my boxes and run all setup manually?" You can get the same result either way, but you'll be making things much more difficult for yourself by just manually setting up everything inside of the container through Bash.

Use a Dockerfile. Future you, and anyone else who needs to deal with that image will thank you.